# Codeguru shows half of the lambda latency's not from our code

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codeguru

We are using aws lambda functions, and enabled CodeGuru for profiling, as following.
Almost 50% percent of the delay are not along our code stack. It happens all the different lambda functions we have. Does that mean lambda runtime takes half of the execution time?
For now, we only have CodeGuru enabled for lambda functions, not on other services. But from their demo CodeGuru, we don't see the second half on the latency part.
Also attaching it below our CodeGuru profiling.
Any insight'll be appreciated!

[image]

[image]